# For what values of $a$ the series $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^n}{n^\sqrt n}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

It's clear that the series converges for $|a| \leq 1$ but what about $|a|>1$?

Comment: $a=1$ implies divergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply root test

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a^n|\over n^{\sqrt{n}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|a|}{n^{(\sqrt{n})^{-1}}}$$

Consider the denominator. Take $\log$ and you can get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}}\stackrel{\text{L'H}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n} =0$$

Therefore the denominator is $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{(\sqrt{n})^{-1}} =e^0 =1$. When $|a| > 1$, the root test shows the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $a > 1$, and define $a > b=\frac{a+1}{2}>1$. One can write $$
\frac{a^n}{n^{\sqrt{n}}} = e^{ n\left( \ln a - \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} \right)  };
$$
and since $\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$, there exists $N>0$ such that for $n \geq N$
$$
e^{ n\left( \ln a - \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} \right)  } \geq e^{ n\left( \ln a - \ln\frac{a}{b} \right)  } = e^{ n\ln b } = b^n
$$
and thus the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}$ diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: If $a>1,$ then $a^n/n^{\sqrt n} > 1$ for large $n.$ This proves the series diverges.

Proof: This is the same as $n\ln a -\sqrt n\ln n > 0,$ or $$\ln a > \frac {\ln n}{\sqrt n}$$ for large $n.$ Since the limit of the right side is $0,$ and $ \ln a > 0,$ we've proved the claim.

Answer (score 0):

The series diverges for $|a|>1$ because 
$$
\frac{a^n} {n^{\sqrt{n}}} = a^{n-\sqrt{n}\log_a(n)}
$$
Apply the ratio test: 
$$
\frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}} = a^{1-\left( \sqrt{n}\log_a(n)- \sqrt{n-1} \log_a(n-1) \right)}
$$
Now 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(  \sqrt{n}\log_a(n)- \sqrt{n-1} \log_a(n-1) \right) 
$$
can be done in a number of ways; my favorite is to write 
$$
\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1} = \sqrt{n} \left( 1 - \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}} \right)  = 
\sqrt{n}\left(1 - \left((1 - \frac{1}{2n} + O(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \right)= 
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}+O(n^{-\frac32}) \\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(  \sqrt{n}\log_a(n)- \sqrt{n-1} \log_a(n-1) \right)  =
\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(  \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n-1} \right) \log_a(n)+O(\frac{1}{n})\\
=O(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}) \to 0
$$

Since 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} a^{1-\left( \sqrt{n}\log_a(n)- \sqrt{n-1} \log_a(n-1) \right)} \to a^1 = a
$$
the ratio test tells us that the series converges of $|a| < 0$ (which we already knew) and diverges for $|a|>0$.